Why does this study claim that the " proportion of true pedophiles among persons with a homosexual erotic development is greater"? than heterosexuals?
According to this study:

Previous investigations have indicated that the ratio of sex offenders against female children vs. offenders against male children is approximately 2:1, while the ratio of gynephiles to androphiles among the general population is approximately 20:1. The present study investigated whether the etiology of preferred partner sex among pedophiles is related to the etiology of preferred partner sex among males preferring adult partners. Using phallometric test sensitivities to calculate the proportion of true pedophiles among various groups of sex offenders against children, and taking into consideration previously reported mean numbers of victims per offender group, the ratio of heterosexual to homosexual pedophiles was calculated to be approximately 11:1. This suggests that the resulting proportion of true pedophiles among persons with a homosexual erotic development is greater than that in persons who develop heterosexually. This, of course, would not indicate that androphilic males have a greater propensity to offend against children.

In between the bolded parts is the claim the study says, yet heterosexual oriented pedophiles outnumber homosexual oriented pedophiles. Why?

Terrible methodology aside, because they're comparing 11:1 to 20:1. Or, said another way, because most people are heterosexual. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_rate and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_rate_fallacy
